# I installed ros1 in windows. Rviz is not rendering/updating properly especially when I try to zoom or change orientation. It is showing trace

Tags: windows, graphics, frame, ros

I installed ros1 melodic in windows. Rviz is not rendering/updating properly especially when I try to zoom or change orientation. It is showing trace of all the rendered graphics object (Grid lines, robots from urdf file, in this case a braccio robot defined by urdf and stl files). Please find the screenshot. The trace disappears if I minimize or maximize the left panel. It appears again if I zoom or change orientation or pan or perform motion of the robot. Laptop: Lenovo Carbon X1 6th Gen default configuration, graphics driver. 26.20.100.6860, graphics card UHD620.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5s6s.png)

Comment: Please add some information about graphics object.

Comment: Done Raj. Thanks.